# De formulario a python para imprimir en consola me abre el archivo python con el editor

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de pasar de un formulario a python para imprimir en consola los valores que han llegado firstname y lastname. Pero al darle al botón, se me abre el editor de código con el archivo prueba.py

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba formulario</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Prueba formulario</h1>

<form action="prueba.py/tomadatos" method="post">
    <label for="fname">Nombre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Luis"><br>
    <label for="lname">Apellido:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Perez"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

**prueba.py**

```
import requests

def tomadatos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nombre = request.POST.get(firstname)
        apellido = request.POST.get(lastname)
        print(nombre)
        print(apellido)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás asumiendo que el manejo de un formulario HTML en Django es similar a lo que se hace en PHP puro. Esto además de ser opuesto a la filosofía del Framework es inseguro y difícil de mantener.

En Django el atributo "action" de un formulario HTML tiene que apuntar a una url válida y registrada en algún archivo urls.py del proyecto, luego debe de ser manejado el método (post o get) por la vista.

En todo caso, deberías de quitar el .py de la action, tal vez has configurado adecuadamente las url y yo asumo algo erróneo:

```
<form action="prueba/tomadatos" method="post">
```

En este momento vos tenés lo siguiente:

```
<form action="prueba.py/tomadatos" method="post">
```

Espero sirva.